# I can't build multiple configuration(s) of a project at the same time in Visual Studio, but I can with MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I want to build two configurations at the same time of a project. Let's say that when I want to build the release version, but I want to build even the debug version (the opposite isn't true).

Starting with *[Use a single Visual Studio solution to build both x86 and x64 at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574075/use-a-single-visual-studio-solution-to-build-both-x86-and-x64-at-the-same-time)* I've tried adding to the .csproj:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Configuration=Debug" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
</Target>
```

And if I try to build the project through MSBuild,

```
MSBuild ConsoleApplication64.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86
```

it works correctly. The two configurations are built correctly and everything is good.

The problem is if I try to build it with Visual Studio: the release version is built correctly, and then it begins to build the debug version, and it gives me:

> Copying file from "obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication64.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication64.
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2868,9): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication64.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication64.exe". Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication64.exe'.

Pre-conditions:

- Windows XP SP3 ITA
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1 English
- The project is an empty console application for C# 4.0 (technically it isn't, but I can reproduce the problem with that).

(Note that to have those messages I've activated the verbosity: normal from menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and Solutions* → *Build and Run* → *MSBuild project build output verbosity*.

After comparing the output of the two "half" runs, the difference is that in the "working" half the `csc` executable is called, and in the other one it isn't:

Release half:

> Task "Csc" (TaskId:13)
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig
>   /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4
>   /define:TRACE /reference:"C:\Programmi\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Programmi\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Programmi\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Programmi\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll"
>   /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+
>   /out:obj\x86\Release\ConsoleApplication64.exe /target:exe Program.cs
>   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\m.alberti-cons\Impostazioni
>   locali\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>   (TaskId:13) Done executing task "Csc". (TaskId:13)

Debug half:

> Task "Csc" (TaskId:41)
>   Done executing task "Csc". (TaskId:41)

After some more tests I've noticed that if the two halves use the same `DefineConstants` then there isn't any problem and everything works, but if they are different (as in release/debug) then it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Can you please try to build in Msbuild at debug configuration first then try to build in Release configuration?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Then it works, but in truth it doesn't do anything. To be clear: Build Debug, Build Release (+ Debug): no error, but: Build Debug, add some lines of code (`Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`), Build Release, the Debug version isn't rebuilt, but no error.

Comment: whether your Visual studio has /p:Platform=x86 or it is anycpu?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu I'm using the stock Console Application, so it has the config for Debug and Release of x86 but not for anycpu.

Answer (score 2):

You can't build inside Visual Studio because of MSBuild's [incremental build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx) mechanism that skips targets marked as already run. The real question here is how to break this incremental build. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5081603/147211) question is very related.

If you build with `/verbosity=diag` you will notice MSBuild reports a bunch of these:

> Target "AssignTargetPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully.

Microsoft aware of this behavior and consider this [by design](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/677499/different-results-when-running-msbuild-within-visual-studio-or-from-console).

A possible workaround, which I strongly advise against it, is invoking the second build using the [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task. The Exec task is merely a command line shell which will eat everything you will feed it with, but in your case it can break the incremental build chain.

```
<Exec Command="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\msbuild $(MSBuildProjectFile) /p:Configuration=Debug" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" />
```

Comment: The `Target "AssignTargetPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully.` is present in both halves of the diagnostic build. I've even tried putting <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck> in the three ProjectGroup (the generic one and the ones for Debug and Release) but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: That was only an example. If you look closely you'll find a bunch of `Previously built successfully` and `skipped, due to false condition`. Internally, VS decides when not to rebuild but that process can be hacked. [this may give you a clue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9130221/147211)