# Visual Studio Builds mutiple times before attaching debugger when executing unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010,C# and trying to execute unit/integration tests. I got integration-test project which references several other projects. When I want to execute my test, it builds again & again, before executing the test. This is the same case when i execute the tests with both Resharper & MSTest. I am sure it has to do with Visual Studio, attaching debugger to the context. As a final attempt, I removed all project references from integration project and when i start execute the tests, i saw the same behaviour. It means, the compilation is not specific to the project and the whole solution is being built. 
I already spent my whole day trying to fix this up. I found a similar project here without any solution
[Multiple rebuilds when choosing "Debug | Start new instance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713558/multiple-rebuilds-when-choosing-debug-start-new-instance)

Since the build is being re-written everytime, I am not sure what exactly causing this issue.

Any pointers, ideas.

Comment: I use c++ for embedded design and when I need to use other projects I must first make them 'static libraries' and import them as such into the project on which I am currently working. By making them static you basically say 'I trust that these work in full and don't need to be compiled again'. I would look into this if I were you, hopefully it will lead to something :) I have no idea what they would be called in Visual Studio but probably something similar...

Comment: I just found this after a quick search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suprisingly, this behaviour didnt occur when I turn off the virus scanner scanner the solution directory. I can make a theory that the build binary signature somehow gets modified during the scan process and it makes the visual studio to rebuild it multiple times