# Difference between 1 succeeded and 1 succeeded or up-to-date in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I would like to clear one concept.
In c#,
when we build(or re-build) a solution,
We sometimes get
`Build: 1 succeeded`

and sometimes,

```
Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date
```

Ok, I know that something in our code would be not as per logic when we get the latter ans.

But, what does it mean `CONCEPTUALLY`?

Comment: My guess is it means the "up-to-date" project didn't really need to be built since nothing has changed since the last build.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does visual studio use to determine that a build is up to date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140003/what-does-visual-studio-use-to-determine-that-a-build-is-up-to-date)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Build: 1 succeeded` in general refer to successful compilation of the solution with `1` project in it.

while

`Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date` means that codes in the project within your solution has not changed, hence compilation was not needed. Hence, `1 Build Success or up-to-date`

Answer (score 4):

It means nothing has changed in the project. VS (well MSBUILD really), decides if it's up to date as follows:

From: [How does MSBuild decide whether it needs to rebuild a C# library or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081603/how-does-msbuild-decide-whether-it-needs-to-rebuild-a-c-sharp-library-or-not)

> If you look in Microsoft.CSharp.targets (the msbuild file for
>   compiling C# projects) the CoreCompile target has a set of Inputs and
>   Outputs defined. These are used to do the dependency checking to see
>   if CoreCompile needs to run. The list of inputs include the c# files,
>   resource files, application icon, strong name key file, and other
>   custom inputs you can define.
>
> If you have a solution and run msbuild on it with diagnostic logging enabled (/v:diag command line parameter), you might see this
>   message if the outputs are up to date:
>
> Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
>
> The targets file is located in the .NET Framework directory (c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 or v4.0.30319.

Answer (score 0):

An "up-to-date" project was previously built successfully, and hasn't changed since that time, so it isn't rebuilt.