# Visual Studio not building InitialTargets or DefaultTargets if project is up to date

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a CS project that depends on some archive files and I have created MSBuild targets to build them. I cannot, however, get MSBuild to build these targets if project's files are up to date.

I have tried referencing the archive targets in the following places:

- The project's before and after build targets
- The project's InitialTarget and DefaultTarget attributes
- In a separate targets file, which I tried to add as a [project reference](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/ProjectReference-Protocol.md) to my project. I'm not sure I used the item correctly though.

When I build, Visual Studio tells me that my project is up to date and does nothing. How can I make it consider my other targets as dependencies?

Comment: If you use the `<Import Project="..\xxx.targets" />` way to call targets, vs won't consider the project is up-to-date if there's any change in the xx.targets file, but if you have several targets you want to execute anyway no matter if the project is up-to-date, rebuild the project instead of build can be more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you build the project in VS IDE. VS IDE has a `up-to-date` check, if the project's output files are up-to-date with respect to their corresponding input files, it won't start build process.

> I cannot, however, get MSBuild to build these targets if project's
>   files are up to date.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15003180/10910450), if the input source files and output assemblies are corresponding up-to-date, VS won't really build and won't call your custom targets.

And according to your description, what you want is to run your target no matter if project file is up-to-date, I'm not sure what you mean `make it consider my other targets as dependencies`.What you really want is to run the custom targets anyway, if so, you can build the project by [command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019#build-the-target) or try **rebuild** instead of **build** button in VS. If I misunderstand anything, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: The VS behavior is what I feared, but I couldn't find anywhere online to confirm it. I don't understand why VS would do this when MSBuild supports [incremental builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds?view=vs-2019). Regarding my quote about making my other targets dependencies, I know that VS will build a project if a project which it references is out of date, even if that project's source files have not changed. I would like to accomplish that behavior with my custom target.

Comment: @ChrisThomas When calling msbuild.exe in VS IDE, there's one up-to-date check process before calling the msbuild I think. And the Incremental builds is something used to determine if we need to skip one target, when vs consider the project isup-to-date, it won't even execute any target in project file. Maybe you can try building the project in command-line, it seems the behavior you want(Incremental builds)  can be accomplished in command-line.